# Why is the column space a subset of $R^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently working on trying to understand column spaces, but I'm struggling to understand one thing. Namely, that if we have a $m × n$ matrix, how does it come that the column space is a subspace of $R^m$. It feels wrong because in the $m × n$ matrix we've actually got n variables and this should mean that we are in $R^n$, right?

Thanks for all help! If there's any good explanations / videos about column spaces, null spaces, rank, and such, I'd be pleased if you could share them with me.

Comment: $m\times n$ matrix means $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Each column has $m$ rows, i.e a column is like $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\vdots\\x_m\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^m$.

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking about matrices as representing systems of equations, with each row representing an equation and each column corresponding to a variable. Another way to think about matrices is as representations of linear transformations from one vector space, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$,  to another vector space, $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. In the equation $Ax=b$, if the matrix $A$ is $m \times n$, then $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $ b\in \mathbb{R}^{m} $.

Comment: Oh okay! Yes @Joe, that's what I was thinking. Thank to both of you! So, for a row space, the same argument holds, but then its a subspace of $R^n$.

Comment: Yes, exact same reasoning gives that the row space is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Related [Row Space/Column Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384101/column-space-row-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your matrix is of size $m×n$. You can find a linear transformation $T:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ ,  $X\mapsto AX$, where $X$ is a column vector of size $n×1$. Column space is a made of all linear combinations of column vectors of a matrix.

[Here](https://youtu.be/9h_Q-R6sXbM) is a link you can go through this.

Answer (score 1):

The span of any set of vectors is a subspace of the vector space they are a subset of. The columns of the matrix are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ so their span is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. If you need a proof of this statement I'd be happy to provide, but it's a fun exercise to do on your own as well.